# OAuth2 OIDC, How/When to give JWT to the browser?

Tags: oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, openid-connect

I'm implementing a SSO solution. Got a general question regarding `authorization code flow` grant type as described [here](https://auth0.com/docs/architecture-scenarios/web-app-sso/part-1).

After a user login, the client app would get an ID token. But I cannot find anywhere how/when a JWT should be given to the browser such that it can set the bearer token in the request header for any subsequent request? Is it something not specified in the standard or I misunderstand something?

Answer (score 1):

The browser does not set the `Authorization` request header automatically. You have to do it yourself using Javascript. This means that a request with such a header must be an AJAX call. If you want to send regular requests through the browser (by navigating to a URL), then you have to use cookies, as they will be automatically added by the browser. (You can keep the value of a token in a cookie and have your backend read a cookie instead of the `Authorization` header)

Comment: Thanks! That what I figure that needs to be done.